# Genymotion is disabled and splashed when using Image Widget in Flutter(Android Studio)

Tags: flutter-layout, genymotion

GenyMotion is turned off and splashed when using Image Widget in Flutter(Android Studio) when running with real device and Android virtual machine it normally only happens on GenyMotion can someone tell me how to fix it  thank

this is my source code
https://github.com/chung19/dicee-flutter.git

`Expanded( child: TextButton( onPressed: () { getDiceNumber(); }, child: Image.asset( 'images/dice$rightDiceNumber.png', cacheHeight: 100, cacheWidth: 100, ), ), ),`

[image]

[image]

Comment: feel free to ask questions if someone needs more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Update, after using Genymotion version Android 5.1, it works normally